# Django deployment on heroku throws django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user

Tags: python, django, sqlite, heroku, django-manage.py

I'm deploying on a free Heroku dyno.
This is my Procfile:

```
release: python manage.py migrate
web: gunicorn app.wsgi --log-file -
```

I've already made migrations locally and I'm deploying through Github. I figured out that the line `release: python manage.py migrate` indeed runs the command on the dyno but doesn't create tables(I've confirmed this by getting into the command line of my Dyno using `heroku run bash` and then check if there are any tables in the `db.sqlite3` file. There were none. I rerun the `migrate` command using the Heroku bash and then the tables were populated in the `db.sqlite3` file. I exited the console, reload my app and tried to login again but it threw the same error, yet again: `django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such table: auth_user`. I logged into Heroku bash again and saw that the tables that I've created in the `db.sqlite3` file are not there anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku uses ephemeral filesystem.
Since SQLite is stored as a file inside the project folder,you can't expect it to be there permanently.
Only project files will remain untouched.
Any files created by your code will be deleted regularly (max 24hours)
Any type of storage should be done using S3 (for static files).
For database,you should use the database service provided by heroku (I use Postgres).

Comment: I'll try using Postgres for now

Comment: Mark it as solved if it solved your problem